# How to Update one table by another table datas using storedprocedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a Table named `Dummy`with marks and student id (3 mark fields are there). I have another one table Applicantdetails this table also contains mark fields. what I want to do is I want to updates Dummy tables marks to Applicantdetails table's marks as per student id. I want to do this by mssql Storedprocedure. Any way to achieve it. If we write in code wise it should be like this

```
 qry="select Applicantid,mark1,mark2,mark3 from Dummy"
 //saved result to Datatable dt
 foreaach(DataRow. rows in dt.rows)
 {
   string id=Convert.ToString(row["ApplicantID"].tostring();
   string mark1=Convert.ToString(row["ApplicantID"].tostring();
   string mark2=Convert.ToString(row["ApplicantID"].tostring();
   string mark3=Convert.ToString(row["ApplicantID"].tostring();
   qry="update Applicantdetails set Mark1=mark1,Mark2=Mark2,Mark3=Mark3
where ApplicantID=id";
  }
```

This format I want to bring in storedprocedure..Please help me

Comment: your code doesn't even compile!

Comment: @dotctor, I jz write asample.This type code howcan i convert to stored procedure format? That I wntto know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Stored procedure would receive @applicationid ? Otherwise it would update all, Create a stored procedure with the following SQL

```
UPDATE A 
SET Mark1= d.mark1, Mark2 = d.mark2, Mark3= d.mark3
FROM ApplicationDetail A
JOIN Dummy d on d.Applicationid = A.Applicationid
```

Comment: Thank You..you saved me from a big matter